QGIS Layout Template - Draw Coordinates Buffer
Is there a way to create a buffer (e.g. 2cm) to prevent the coordinates drawn around the edge of a map from overlapping with each other or other features in the layout? I have experimented with different expressions but nothing has worked to date.

Please include screenshots illustraring your problem, as well as a more detailed description of "i have experimented with different expressions".

You speak about the atlas feature? If so, in the Item Property of the Map, you have the entry Controlled by Atlas, where you can define a Margin around feature. Set it to 0%. If your problem is another one, please describe it in more detail so that we understand it.
